# Is it secure to login or signup facebook or google accounts through proxy web servers?

Tags: facebook, security

I visited some proxy sites(Ninjaproxy,proxyblind) to get access facebook annoymously. But, they gave duplicate facebook homepage (In ninja proxy facebook's js doesn't work! and In proxyblind gave different homepage instead its official homepage!). pls verify this is secure to login or signup facebook or other accounts through webproxy servers ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can verify that the SSL certificate is valid for facebook.com and that the connection is done over SSL, you are safe even when going over a proxy. If not, you are likely victim to an MITM attack.